# Prolog: find all numbers of unique digits that can be formed from a list of digits

Tags: list, numbers, prolog, digits

The best thing I could come up with so far is this function:

> ```
>  numberFromList([X], X) :-  
>     digit(X), !.  
>  numberFromList(List, N) :-  
>     member(X, List),     
>     delete(List, X, LX),  
>     numberFromList(LX, NX),  
>     N is NX * 10 + X.
> ```

where `digit/1` is a function verifying if an atom is a decimal digit.

The `numberFromList(List, N)` finds all the numbers that can be formed with **all** digits from `List`.
E.g. `[2, 3] -> 23, 32`. 
but I want to get this result: `[2, 3] -> 2, 3, 23, 32`

I spent a lot of hours thinking about this and I suspect you might use something like `append(L, _, List)` at some point to get lists of lesser length.

I would appreciate any contribution.

Comment: How do you want the numbers? In a list or one at a time on backtracking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing case when you skip digit from list.

```
 numberFromList([X], X) :-  
    digit(X), !.  
 numberFromList(List, N) :-
    member(X, List),     
    delete(List, X, LX),
    numberFromList(LX, NX),  
    ( % use X
        N is NX * 10 + X
    ; % skip X
        N = NX
    ).
```

BTW, as @Roland Illig mentioned there is `select(X, List, LX)` to replace `member(X, List), delete(List, X, LX)`

Answer (score 0):

The predicate `unique/3` generates all lists of length up to `MaxLen` consisting of symbols from `Symbols`. The generated lists are stored in `L`, once at a time.

```
unique(MaxLen, Symbols, L) :-
    between(0, MaxLen, Len),
    length(L, Len),
    unique(Symbols, L).
```

The helper predicate for generating the lists.

```
unique(_, []).
unique(Set, [H|R]) :-
    select(H, Set, ReducedSet),
    unique(ReducedSet, R).
```

A simple program for demonstrating the above predicate:

```
main :-
    unique(5, [2,3], L),
    write(L), nl, fail.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using SWI-PROLOG built-ins for [`atomic_list_concat/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/2), [`atom_number/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_number/2) and [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=lists:select/3). Firstly, the entry point refers to an implementation using an initially empty accumulator:

```
numberFromList(L, N) :-
    numberFromList(L, [], N).
```

The predicate `numberFromList/3` either accumulates digits (unchecked) from the list, or not, leaving choicepoints:

```
numberFromList([_|Cs], Acc, N) :-
    numberFromList(Cs, Acc, N).
numberFromList([C|Cs], Acc, N) :-
    numberFromList(Cs, [C|Acc], N).
```

The final clause of `numberFromList/3` permutes the accumulated list of digits and concatenates them into an atom, which is then converted to a number as required:

```
numberFromList([], [C|Cs], N) :-
    permute([C|Cs], PermutedAcc),
    atomic_list_concat(PermutedAcc, AN),
    atom_number(AN, N).
```

Sometimes `permute/2` (as defined manually below) may be available as a built-in, such as [`permutation/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=permutation/2). Here is a manual definition using [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=lists:select/3):

```
permute([], []).
permute([E|Es], [E0|PL]) :-
    select(E0, [E|Es], Rem),  
    permute(Rem, PL).
```

If you want a list of all the results and don't want `numberFromList/2` to backtrack itself, you could wrap the call to `numberFromList/3` (with the empty accumulator in the first clause of `numberFromList/2`) in a [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) call.